# Can't complete payment for event registration when approval is required

Tags: civievent, stripe

I've set up an event on my site, where members are allowed to register but registrations must be approved.  The registration process goes fine.  I then change a registrant's status from "Awaiting Approval" to "Pending from Approval", and the registrant gets another email with a link to confirm registration and complete the process (make payment). The registrant can enter credit card info, but then gets this message:

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the
> moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider
> with more details about what action you were performing when this
> occurred. Property 'contactID' has not been set.

Any ideas?
Claudia

Comment: Are you using stripe payment?

Comment: Yes, Stripe.  I should add, I've made several attempts to register for a dummy event, with a registration fee of $1.00.  Each time, I get the error.  But my credit card shows a pending charge of $1.00 for each of those attempts.  I'm wondering if the problem is with Stripe.

Comment: What is your stripe version?

Comment: Stripe version 6.6

Comment: Just updated to 6.6.1.  Still the same problem.

Comment: Do you get the same problem with the dummy payment processor instead of Stripe?